# SQL - Query to sum up last days events

Tags: sql

I have a BigQuery table that looks like:

- user_id
- bought_from_category: games / movies / equipment
- game_name (only in case of game)
- movie_name (only in case of movie)
- equipment_id (you get the idea..)
- time

(I know it's a bad idea to design a table this way but let's ignore that for now)

I need to fetch the following data:

- A list of all the user_ids that in the last x days had more than y different items
  (different = if a user bought the same game twice it only count as one)
- for each item in the list also the number of actual items bought (number should be bigger than y)

A result example could be:

```
+---------+----------------+
| user_id | n_items_bought |
+---------+----------------+
|  111111 |            101 |
|  222222 |            112 |
|  333333 |            101 |
|  444444 |            107 |
+---------+----------------+
```

Meaning there were 4 users with more than y = 100 **different** purchases in the last x days.

Comment: Which `DBMS` are you using? `SQL` is a programming language. `Oracle`, `SQL Server`, `mySQL`, etc. Additionally, it isn't clear how your data is structured. Can you please post some example data? Help us help you :)

Comment: @wundermahn Right, I am using google BigQuery to save this data. the structure is described above :)

Comment: this doesn't help us understand what your data looks like, what issues you have, and what you are expected. For example, is every day a row? Is the row only by transactions? Can a user have a row at a time but no transactions made? Example data helps us answer these questions -- we can't help you without it.

Comment: Next time please don't show an image, but paste the data as text in your request. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks! but how do I show tables here? is there a doc i missed?

Comment: First you copy your data to the clipboard. Then you can edit it, either directly in the request editor or in a text editor or with some tool. I use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for this. Then in your request either mark the table as "code" (with the `{}` button) or enclose it in <pre> and </pre>. (I've just edited your request accordingly, so you can see what this looks like.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT DISTINCT`. You are looking for distinct category + name. The name can be in either of three columns, so use `COALESCE` on them.

```
select
  user_id,
  count(*) as total_items,
  count(distinct bought_from_category || '/' || coalesce(game_name, movie_name, equipment_id)) as distinct_items
from mytable
where time >= date_sub(current_date(), interval 20 day)
having count(distinct bought_from_category || '/' || coalesce(game_name, movie_name, equipment_id)) >= 100
order by user_id;
```

In Google BigQuery, `COUNT DISTINCT` is just an approximation, though, when it comes to larger values. It suffices for 100 distinct rows (default is exactness up to 1000 distinct values.) You can use another limit or use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` if you want this to work with higher amounts.